# Autoloading a particular driver, based on a detected specific kernel

Tags: debian, shell-script, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, startup

I need  to write a *script* and determining its *placement* within Debian 7.9 filesystem. The script needs to be executed automatically on startup and, after checking what kernel is currently loaded (2.6.x vs. 3.2.x), unload the incorrect network driver, if loaded, and load the correct one. This question is the follow-up for my [prior question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252813/148105) and represents the only missing piece of that puzzle, as I've already figured out cross-kernel compiling of network driver by myself.

In terms of the location, I think that the script should be placed into "/etc/rcX.d" directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location you guessed is nearly correct. But `/etc/rcX.d` directories usually contain only links to scripts in `/etc/init.d/`, so that a script only has to exist once but can be called at different runlevels.

Comment: Happy to can help – if you liek you can also 'accept' this as correct answer, like mot people are used to on StackOverflow

Comment: Sorry, forgot to accept. Done. Happy holidays! :-)